# C#.NET DataTable First & Last record value - Exception: Unable to cast object

Tags: c#, .net, group-by, datatable

I am trying to create a grouped summary data table from a detailed list table.
Key & Sum functions are working nicely as expected.
However when the First() & Last() functions are added, it throws an exceptions.

```cs
// The following codes are not given here, as they are working well.
// sql2 - is a query to filter data between two dates
// conn - is connection to database file

DataTable ds2 = new DataTable();
adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql2, conn);
adapter.Fill(ds2);

try
{
    DataTable ds2Sum = ds2.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(r => r["MaterialName"])
        .Select(g =>
        {
            var row = ds2.NewRow();

            row["MaterialName"] = g.Key;
        // ................................ Exception error here
            row["OpeningBalance"] = g.First();
            row["Quantity"] = g.Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r["Quantity"]));
        // ................................ Exception error here
            row["ClosingBalance"] = g.Last();  

            return row;
        }).CopyToDataTable();
    dataGridView2.DataSource = ds2Sum;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Message:" + ex.Message.ToString() + "\nData:" + ex.Data.ToString() + "\nSource:" + ex.Source.ToString());
}
```

**Note:** The try{} statement is added temporarily to catch the exception details.

**Exception Message:**

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'System.IConvertible'. Couldn't store <System.Data.DataRow> in OpeningBalance Column. Expected type is Double.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtT1H.png)

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

To get a grouped summary of Material data with Opening & Closing balances.
And display in a Grid View.

Comment: `g.First()` is a row. Shouldn't it be `g.First()["OpeningBalance"]`?

Comment: Thanks. How can I get [OpeningBalance] column value from g.First() row to output table ds2Sum?

Comment: That's precisely what I have shown in my last comment: `row["OpeningBalance"] = g.First()["OpeningBalance"];` and `row["ClosingBalance"] = g.Last()["ClosingBalance"];`. But it would probably easier to execute a query like `SELECT MaterialName, OpeningBalance, SUM(Quantity) As SumOfQuantity, ClosingBalance FROM myTbl GROUP BY MaterialName, OpeningBalance, ClosingBalance` or even an INSERT INTO query.